# What triggers the "Juiced" effect?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Just started playing MW3 multiplayer, and I noticed that sometimes I received a buff called *Juiced* upon respawn. This buff increased my speed momentarily (presumably so I could get back in the fight), but it left me wondering: what caused it?

Is it something I can trigger intentionally? Is it random?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Juiced** is a Deathstreak Reward received *when you've died four times in a row without a kill*, (3 times with Hardline Pro). You run faster than if you'd just used Lightweight, and it occurs on every respawn until you kill someone.

---

http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Deathstreak

http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juiced

Answer (score 5):

Juiced kicks in after a sequence of deaths and continues to have effect until the next time you get a kill.

It kicks in after 4 deaths, or 3 if using Hardline Pro.

Comment: Props for that go to my good editor, @Cem22lp